# R correction of plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a code to plot histogram  in R that works fine:

```
fun_hist <- function(c, E, HS, log_EC_50) {
  df <- data.frame(log_c = c, response = V({{c}}, {{E}}, {{HS}}, {{log_EC50}}))
  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes( response)) +  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.03)
}
```

I want to correct my histogram so that its bars have a graphic design as in the attached photo.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty similar to my eye:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(response = rnorm(25000, 15, 2))

ggplot(df, aes(response)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = 'black', fill = "#547fbf") +
  xlim(c(0, 24)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>